# aws describe-instances query tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to filter my output for describe-instances tot show the following:
- instanceId
- Device + Volume
- Tag[Key==Name]

The expression I have is

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query "Reservations[*].Instances[].[InstanceId, BlockDeviceMappings[*].{DeviceName:DeviceName,VolumeName:Ebs.VolumeId}, Tags[*]]"
```

But this gives me output where all the tags are showing. How can I change this to only the "Name" tag?

Comment: also check: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/621

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for a JMESPath [Filter Expression](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#filter-expressions).  Try this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[InstanceId, BlockDeviceMappings[*].{DeviceName:DeviceName,VolumeName:Ebs.VolumeId}, Tags[?Key==`Name`]]'
```

Comment: when I do that, I get a " Illegal token value '?Key==`Name`]]'  " error

Comment: I've put it as answered because even though I can't test it, it's due to my installed version. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[ [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==`tag_component_name`].Value][0][0] ]' --output json --profile myprofile --region us-east-1
```

Make sure to change the --output, --profile and --region paramaters

Answer (score 4):

To check instances with a particular tag.

```
aws --profile account1 ec2 describe-instances \
--filters "Name=tag-key,Values=Product" "Name=tag-value,Values=test" \
--region ap-southeast-1 --output table
```